# Emgu/OpenCV: Event for VideoCapture.QueryFrame() finished.

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Here is the basic idea of my code:

```
    private void CaptureCameraFrame()
    {
        Capture = new VideoCapture();
        CameraModel.Instance.CameraViewMat = Capture.QueryFrame();

        // do stuff with queried matrix here

        if(noAbortCondition)
        {
            CaptureCameraFrame();
        }
    }
```

The method should run in a separate thread updating my GUI with the current image after processing. 
Only Problem is, that I get two different kinds of error:

1. Attempt to read/write protected memory: This happens on the second runthrough 
   of the method.
2. I get an null-reference error using `CameraModel.Instance.CameraViewMat right after querying the frame.

The two issues seem to be connected, seems like `QueryFrame()` runs asynchronously from the rest of the code and isn't done when the program jumps to the next step. 
Question is: How can I make sure, that querying the image from the camera is finished, and I can use the information in the matrix as well as start a new query?

In all the examples I have found this is done by using time, but I would like to start with a new frame as soon as processing on the last frame is done.

I haven't really done much in C# when it comes to threading, but what I understand in such cases one would use the `async`and `await`keywords to make sure a method in an asynchronous method is finished. However I wasn't able to make a working implementation in this case.

Comment: On thing to add: If I remove the recursion I manage to capture a static image. So from that side of things, everything should be working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating `VideoCapture` class instance repeatedly and even not disposing of it. Create your `VideoCapture` instance only once and use them for your task. At the end dispose it.

```
public YourConstructor()
{
    Capture = new VideoCapture();
}
private void CaptureCameraFrame()
{
    CameraModel.Instance.CameraViewMat = Capture.QueryFrame();

    // do stuff with queried matrix here

    if(noAbortCondition)
    {
        CaptureCameraFrame();
    }
}
```

Hopefully, it will work for you!

Comment: Thx, this definitely helped. Now I only have to figure out how to put the method into another task, as I here also get an exception concerning protected memory. Maybe this has to do with access privilege of the thread/task....

Comment: Edit: found the thread issue: Shouldn't try to update variables belonging to the GUI thread from the new task^^

Comment: You cannot access GUI from an external thread directly, You can invoke your GUI related code on GUI thread using this.Invoke() from an external thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread See this.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the provided help!